# intuitive explanation why rank equal dimension of column space

Tags: linear-algebra, intuition, matrix-rank

A nxn, x and B are both  nx1
Ax=B

First show that if rows are all independent then column are all independent:

Intuitively:  n independent rows  (representing n “non-parallel” equations) in n unknowns means the system of equations has a unique solution (the planes or whatever intersect in one point)
The same thing stated from the point of view of the column space: there is only one possible coordinate for B using the columns of A as a coordinate system.
If there is only one possible coordinate for B using column vectors of A then those column vectors must be linearly independent.(obvious no?)
From here its easy to generalize to cases where some rows are dependent as well, just take the smallest square matrices that has only independent rows and then add the dependent row...?
Not rigorous (almost though) but this really explains it no?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because how rigorous this proof of a well-known result is is opinion based.

Comment: going from here to include the cases where there are dependent rows and columns is not quite clear but this does succinctly explain why it must be true if everything is independent. I do this because all the other explanations were very technical and I believe this is truly an intuitive explanation I couldn’t find anywhere...

Comment: @Kurt G. Am I wrong?

Comment: I don't think so. Everyone has their favourite way of proving well-known results.